# Function returns string on first call, and an object on subsequent calls

Tags: php, mysql, orm, propel

I'm a little bit baffled by this, so I'm hoping someone can shed some light on it for me.

I have a function which is meant to return a column `Status` from one of my tables, `visit`.

```
function someFunction($visitId = null) {
  $visit = VisitQuery::create()
    ->select(array('Status'))
    ->findPk($visitId);
}
```

If I `var_dump($visit)`, when calling the function for the **first time**, it outputs:

```
string '1' (length=1)
```

Subsequent, **identical** calls to the function however seem to return an entire object:

```
object(Visit)[30]
  protected 'startCopy' => boolean false
  protected 'id' => int 362
  protected 'job_id' => int 351
  protected 'company_id' => int 2
  protected 'type_id' => int 1
  protected 'visit_date' => string '2013-08-23 00:00:00' (length=19)
  protected 'status' => string '1' (length=1)
  ...
```

I'm calling the function for the first time with an `(int) $visitId` passed via a posted form:

```
var_dump($visitId); // int 362
```

Subsequent calls are made with an `(int) $visitId` which is returned from another function, `saveVisit()` (which uses Propel to save the record - I believe this *may* have something to do with it).

```
$visitId = saveVisit($visitId);
var_dump($visitId); // int 362
```

I tried to do some debugging, and for some reason the query issued to MySQL is different between the first function call and subsequent ones:

```
var_dump($con->getLastExecutedQuery());

SELECT visit.STATUS AS "Status" FROM `visit` WHERE visit.ID=362 // 1st call
SELECT `ID`, `JOB_ID`, `COMPANY_ID`, `TYPE_ID`, `VISIT_DATE`, `STATUS`, `REMIND`, `PRINTED` FROM `visit` WHERE `ID` = 362 // 2nd call
SELECT `ID`, `JOB_ID`, `COMPANY_ID`, `TYPE_ID`, `VISIT_DATE`, `STATUS`, `REMIND`, `PRINTED` FROM `visit` WHERE `ID` = 362 // 3rd call
```

Can anyone tell me why or how this is happening?

I'm using Propel 1.6.

---

Propel's `create()` method:

```
public static function create($modelAlias = null, $criteria = null)
{
    if ($criteria instanceof VisitQuery) {
        return $criteria;
    }
    $query = new VisitQuery();
    if (null !== $modelAlias) {
        $query->setModelAlias($modelAlias);
    }
    if ($criteria instanceof Criteria) {
        $query->mergeWith($criteria);
    }

    return $query;
}
```

Propel's `findPk()` method:

```
public function findPk($key, $con = null)
{
    if ($con === null) {
        $con = Propel::getConnection($this->getDbName(), Propel::CONNECTION_READ);
    }
    // As the query uses a PK condition, no limit(1) is necessary.
    $this->basePreSelect($con);
    $criteria = $this->isKeepQuery() ? clone $this : $this;
    $pkCols = $this->getTableMap()->getPrimaryKeyColumns();
    if (count($pkCols) == 1) {
        // simple primary key
        $pkCol = $pkCols[0];
        $criteria->add($pkCol->getFullyQualifiedName(), $key);
    } else {
        // composite primary key
        foreach ($pkCols as $pkCol) {
            $keyPart = array_shift($key);
            $criteria->add($pkCol->getFullyQualifiedName(), $keyPart);
        }
    }
    $stmt = $criteria->doSelect($con);

    return $criteria->getFormatter()->init($criteria)->formatOne($stmt);
}
```

My function to retrieve the visit status:

```
function getVisitStatus($visitId = null) {
  if (empty($visitId)) {
    return false;
  }
  try {
    $visit = VisitQuery::create()
      ->select(array('Status'))
      ->findPk($visitId);
  } catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage(); exit;
  }
  if (is_null($visit)) {
    return false;
  }
  return $visit;
}
```

The function which saves a visit record:

```
function saveVisit($data = null) {  
  if (empty($data)) {
    return false; 
  }     
  try {     
    $visit = (!empty($data['visit_id'])) ? VisitQuery::create()->findPk($data['visit_id']) : new Visit();   
    if (!is_object($visit)) {
      return false;
    }

    $visitDataMap = array(
      'JobId'  => 'job_id',
      'TypeId'  => 'type_id',
      'VisitDate'  => 'visit_date',
      'Status' => 'status',
      'CompanyId' => 'engineer_id',
      'Remind'  => 'remind'
    );  

    $visitData = array();
    foreach ($visitDataMap as $column => $value) {
      if (!empty($data[$value])) {
        $visitData[$column] = $data[$value];
      }
    }   
    $visit->fromArray($visitData);
    $visit->save();
    return $visit->getId(); 
  } catch (PropelException $e) { 
    echo $e->getMessage(); exit; 
  }
}
```

Comment: I would say that the problem lies in `VisitQuery::create()`. Can you show the code for the `create` function?

Comment: Looks like first time it would create a new visit and return back `1` and for each subsequent request it will return that very object which it created before, can you post the complete code of that function

Comment: @ØHankyPankyØ I've added the complete function to the question

Comment: Ok, now can you please paste the code of these methods: `findPk` and `VisitQuery::create`

Comment: @ØHankyPankyØ I've posted all of the relevant code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that on the first call will grab your data but then put a copy of the full object in to the instance pool. I am not sure if this is a bug or valid behaviour (your code would suggest the former, but I'd love to hear from someone who knows more about Propel such as a dev) but you can stop it happening with:

```
VisitPeer::clearInstancePool();
```

Bear in mind you're losing a bit of caching from other queries you might have done here with the `visit` relation.

You will be able to confirm this by adding an echo in the `BaseVisitPeer.php` file. You will see something like this:

```
public static function getInstanceFromPool($key)
{
    if (Propel::isInstancePoolingEnabled()) {
        if (isset(VisitPeer::$instances[$key])) {
            return VisitPeer::$instances[$key];
        }
    }

    return null; // just to be explicit
}
```

If you add an echo somewhere inside the `if (isset(VisitPeer::$instances[$key])) {` statement, you should see it appear only after the second and subsequent calls. If you were to comment this whole if statement out then you would get the same result back each time - the one you correctly get back from your original call.

Hope that helps!